# remove specific attributes(columns) of weka instances

Tags: java, weka

I've done kind of attribute selection(Information gain) in Weka. After that it returns new data with the new arrange of attributes due to the importance of each attribute within information gain method. I want to remove one or more columns of new data to just have informative attribute in my dataset.
Here you can see my code:

```
    Instances data = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("iris.arff")));

    InfoGainAttributeEval eval = new InfoGainAttributeEval();
    Ranker search = new Ranker();

    AttributeSelection attSelect = new AttributeSelection();
    attSelect.setEvaluator(eval);
    attSelect.setSearch(search);
    attSelect.SelectAttributes(data);

    int[] indices = attSelect.selectedAttributes();

    data = attSelect.reduceDimensionality(data); //re-arrange attributes but not remove them
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Remove`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Remove.html) filter to accomplish this. Specifically, something along these lines should achieve the desired effect:

```
Remove removeFilter = new Remove();
removeFilter.setAttributeIndicesArray(indices);
removeFilter.setInvertSelection(true);
removeFilter.setInputFormat(data);
Instances newData = Filter.useFilter(data, removeFilter);
```

This assumes that `indices` contains the indices of attributes that you want to keep. If it contains the indices of the attributes you want to remove, the delete the call to the `setInvertSelection` method.

Comment: How does the indices look like? Any example?

Comment: You can can define `indices` as something like this: `int[] indices = {0, 3, 4, 5}` where `0, 3, 4, 5` are the attribute indices of the attributes that you want to remove.